# PHP array_sum not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query an SQL table, and then have all the values from one column (it's a "tinyint(1)") added up and then printed, using array_sum. (Currently there are only two rows).

When both rows have a "1" in that column, it gives 2, the correct answer. And when they are both "0" it gives  0, correct again. But when one is "1" and one "0" it gives 2, not 1.

This is my code

    

`$con = mysql_connect("XXX","XXX","XXX");

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("XXX_test", $con);

$day = $_GET["day"];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT $day FROM sites");

if (!$query)
  {
  die('Could not query: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);

echo array_sum($rows);

mysql_close($con);


?>`

Thanks for any help.

**--UPDATE--**
I just solved this myself.

With this, if you want to know:
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT name, SUM($day) AS Alerts FROM sites");

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {
  echo $row['Alerts'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

Comment: Based on your code nothing is insinuating that `$rows` is an array. If you were `$rows[] = mysql_fetch_result($query,0);` _then_ summed it I would wonder why it's not working. But you're getting a key-value array back, so what are you expecting to sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this myself.

With this, if you want to know:
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT name, SUM($day) AS Alerts FROM sites");

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {
  echo $row['Alerts'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

This in fact *never* works correctly.

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

That line only ever fetches the first row. The second row is never retrieved.

The reason it gives `2` using `array_sum` is that `mysql_fetch_array` gets the result in two different formats, with keys both by name and number. So you'll get something like this:

```
array(
    0 => '1',
    'Tuesday' => '1'
)
```

Obviously this will always be `2` or `0`.

You should almost certainly do a count on the DB server:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sites WHERE $day=1
```

Note, however, that your biggest current problem is the enormous gaping SQL injection hole. Sanitise your input.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by the last two sentences?

Comment: @ACarter Read up on SQL injection. Basically, with your code as it currently is, any malicious user could execute arbitrary SQL on your database.

Comment: Oh, yes. When it is finished, I am planning to add a check, so the SQL connection doesn't even start unless a POST parameter is the same as a 'password' given in the code. But thanks for saying that.

Comment: So if the new code is:

    `$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sites WHERE $day=1");`

How do I print it?
Thanks

Comment: No, that won't necessarily help. In this case, you should probably check that `$day` is one of the possible days of the week. I'm not sure your database schema (days of the week as column names?) is well designed, but nonetheless... You should be able to do `$row = mysql_fetch_row($query); $num = $row[0];`

Comment: _The database thing is a boolean (int(1)) for each day, so each row has a list of true or falses for each day (I ws going to store this in an array, but then found out you can't use arrays in SQL)_

**Anyway**, I now have this:
`$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM($day) AS Occurances FROM sites");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($query); 

$num = $row[0];

echo $num;`

And this seems to give random numbers, 2 or 3, not the sum of the given column. What I can't do is print the number from the SQL query on it's own, with nothing else.

Thanks alot, ACarter.

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_fetch_array()` only fetches one row at a time.  You need to fetch the rows in a while loop.  Then you can either append the results to an array and sum those, or sum them in the loop.  You can also `SUM` in mysql anyway, so you might look into using that.

I'm also obligated to suggest that you use PDO or some other DB wrapper instead of `mysql_`.  You also need to escape variables you use in queries under most circumstances, especially if they come from `_GET`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing it in the mysql query:

```
SELECT SUM($day) FROM sites
```

also, please escape the $day variable.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "escape the variable"?

Comment: $day = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['day'], $con); doing this, you prevent sql injection attacks. right now, you just pass the gat-variable without protecting it from bad input

Answer (score 1):

More of a comment:

[`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum) can not work with the array you're passing to it. You need to pass an array for what the function actually works, like `array(1, 2, 3)` which will give you `6` then.

Next to that, let MySQL itself calculate the SUM (or COUNT?), so it's easier to handle in your script as others have posted.